# How to add plugin (npm package) NodeMailer to Gulp 4?

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp, node-modules, nodemailer

I have a dilemma. There is a working project in Gulp 4, I'm trying to connect the npm NodeMailer package to it.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

gulp.task('nodemailer', function (cb) {
  pump([gulp.src('app/js/nodemailer.js'), gulp.dest(destination)], cb);
});
```

Please give me advice how to connect NodeMailer to my main.js file. Or how to make a task that will move the NodeMailer to the 'app/js' folder. Thank you for your attention

I tried to add nodemailer directly after installing via npm i nodemailer, but I got an error when importing. The browser swears on the path to NodeMailer when I call via require